# How to link my Azure VM running SQL server to my on-premise domain or Active Directory?

Tags: sql-server, azure

I'm kinda new to cloud/azure. I have set up a VM running SQL Server using default templates and settings like dynamic IP and name etc.

- Can I connect it to my on premise domain or AD?
- What are the exact steps and prerequisites for it?

Comment: Start here [Step-By-Step: Syncing An On Premise AD with Azure Active Directory](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/canitpro/2014/05/13/step-by-step-syncing-an-on-premise-ad-with-azure-active-directory/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.  You'll need to have a site to site VPN between Azure and your environment.

Once that's one you've got a couple of options.

1. You can change the DNS settings on the vNet to point to your office domain controllers.
2. Add domain controllers to Azure (with static IPs), then change the vNet to use the Azure DCs as for authentication.

Once one of those is done, reboot your VM and you should be able to add it to your domain. We do this for clients all the time, and we've done it with our 
lab, and it works perfectly.

The product Azure Active Directory isn't needed to do this at all.

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned by in the comment by **SqlWorldWide**, syncing your on-premise AD to Azure AD is a good option. One of the benefits of doing this is that when there is an interruption in the connectivity between your on-prem environment and Azure, you will still be able to authenticate against Azure AD.

Another option we have implemented at a few clients is creating a permanent VPN between your Azure environment and on-prem environment using this guide: [Create a Site-to-Site connection in the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-site-to-site-resource-manager-portalhttps://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-site-to-site-resource-manager-portal). This allows you to treat the VPN as if it was just another server in your on-prem environment. The challenge with this approach is working with your networking team to set up your organisation's firewall to establish the IPSec VPN.

Comment: Once you have a VPN or ExpressRoute connection to your Azure VNet you may want to place a Domain Controller Replica in Azure to handle DNS and Authentication traffic without routing on-prem.  Also having a DC replica as your DNS server makes it simple to join the domain.